# C#:How to use the simplistic code to add uncertain condition to where clauses?

Tags: c#, linq

as title said ,I want to add uncertain condition to  where clause,for exaplme ,I want 3 or more parameters I want to pass to linq,but only not null condition I want to pass.I found if I use normal way ,i have to waste a lot of line to write code,xd~;so the code looks like this:

```
 public PaginationModel<UserOrdersDto> GetAllOrdersDescPager
        (string userName, string age, string sex, string email,PagerDto model)
    {
        IList<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            orders = _orderService.Filter<Orders, long>(x => x.Id > 0&&x.userName==userName,
                x => x.Id, model.PageSize * (model.CurrentPage - 1),
                model.PageSize, true);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
        {
            orders = _orderService.Filter<Orders, long>(x => x.Id > 0
            &&x.userName==userName&&x.Age==age,
   x => x.Id, model.PageSize * (model.CurrentPage - 1),
   model.PageSize, true);

        }

    }
```

I want to achieve looks like this:

```
public PaginationModel<UserOrdersDto> GetAllOrdersDescPager
        (string userName, string age, string sex, string email,PagerDto model)
    {
        IList<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            condition += userName;
        }
         if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
        {

            condition += age;
        }

        orders = _orderService.Filter<Orders, long>(x => x.Id > 0
  && condition
  x => x.Id, model.PageSize * (model.CurrentPage - 1),
model.PageSize, true);

    }
```

**Edit:Filter method you can uderstand it to Where**,

it looks like this.

```
            orders = _orderList.Where(x => x.Id > 0
  && condition);
```

Comment: There is no `Where` clauses in your sample... Why simply chaining `.Where` calls not work for you?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry ,Filter means Where, it is a method I make .

Comment: Why cant you just chain where as Alexei suggested?